# Power series of function $f(x)=1/x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

If we know the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$, is it possible to derive the series of $1/x$ from it?

Comment: Can't you just set $x$ equal to $(1-x)$ in your formula?

Answer (score 3):

As $\frac1x$ is not analytic (it isn't even continuous at $0$) it cannot have a [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) around $x=0$.

On the other hand, it has a [Laurant series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) which is $\frac1x$

Comment: He didn't say he was looking for an expansion around 0.

Comment: @Vik78, Actually, I thought about Taylor series.

Comment: Then you can only get power-series around $x=a$ for some non-zero $a$.

Comment: @Vik78 How do you know that the OP is male?

Comment: Idk, it was a verbal slip I guess. Apologies to OP if I was mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

Following man_in_green_shirt's suggestion, you can substitute $(1-x)$ into the power series for $\frac{1}{1-x}$ to get a power series for $\frac{1}{x}$. Since the original series converges for $x\in (-1,1)$, this series for $\frac{1}{x}$ converges in $(0, 2)$.